# Best practice to load a static file into memory once and share among all API requests

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET Web Api project and inside my project, I have a few plain text files that basically act as static templates. Each API request that is made contains data that will substitute values inside a copy of these templates(so as to preserve the original) and then written to disk for further processing.

The template files itself are very small(< 100 lines). What is the best way to have these files or the text inside the files always available in memory so I don't have to open and close the FileStream for each request?

Does a IMemoryCache make sense when the values are always static? Should I store the text as a constant in a static class? Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Or Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream / Build Action = Embedded resource.

Comment: as long as your template is not going to change IMemoryCache is ok.